# Git working copy into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I can't figure out why I can't get a working copy from a git repository into Eclipse PHP Explorer.

I think to have followed the steps I have been reading:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Cloning_Remote_Repositories
- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html

But at the end of the procedure I don't have the code at the PHP Explorer. But the way, at Git perspective I can see the git repository.

The only options I can see at Team context-menu, are:

- Apply Patch
- Share code

By "share Code" option, the project files are moved into the git repository folder. By doing this:

- the project tree parent has detected the git repository, I can see at the root tree [gitpoject git]
- at the project properties, on Git section, I can see the Git repository data correctly
- The Team contextual-menu has now the expected Git commands

If I do a commit from the root-tree, the Commit windows is shown and wants to add the Eclipse project structure.

But I can't see the code holded into the git repository into the project.

I tried to clone the git repository with "Git Bash" by one side, and import this folder into an existing project without luck.

Anyone could help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this not responds completely the problem I have explained, the only way I can have a working copy into the Eclipse PHP Explorer is by:

1. Make a git clone through Git Bash
2. Create a new project (PHP Project) and select "Create project at exisiting location" for Contents

By selecting the directory I have the repository cloned, I can see the contents of this repo now at the PHP Explorer and use the Git tools.

If someone could clarify why the procedure I have followed has not worked I will appreciate to understand it.